# rails: data being deleted on page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, hyperlink, helper

I have a method in my application helper that is meant to deactivate a task in my database.

Application helper:

```
  def link_to_destroy_task(task_id)
    Task.find(task_id).deactivate
  end
```

Model:

```
def self.deactivate()
  update_attribute(:active, false)
end
```

View:

```
<ol id="tasks">
  <% @Tasks.each do |task| %>
      <%content_tag_for :li, task do %>
      <span class ="handle"> [drag] </span>
      <%= link_to task.name, :controller => "com_tasks", :action => "edit", :id => task.id %>
      <%= link_to_function '[Delete]', link_to_destroy_task(task.id) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end  %>
</ol>
```

For some reason when the page loads it is deleting everything from the list. Not just switching active to false. It is completely wiping it from the database.

I am using fixtures, so I reload all the test data, and I can refresh once to see the data again, but the next time I reload it is gone.

I have changed the name of the method to 'deactivate' because I think destroy is already taken, but the method is still being run without being clicked.   It isn't deleting anymore, but it is deactivating everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're calling `deactivate` in your view for each item!  The 2nd parameter to your link_to_function is running the actual deactivation.

I think you're misunderstanding `link_to_function` - it doesn't run a ruby function when clicked, it runs a *javascript* function you've created.  The 2nd parameter needs to be a string that contains a javascript function. Rails would have no way to run a ruby method in somebody's browser.

Here's a link to the documentation, which should get you on the right track:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/link_to_function

Comment: Ohk. I originally had it in the controller than i thought I was meant to move it to a helper.   Is there a way to create a link to a action in the application controller? I wanted it to be available from different views from different controllers. And I didn't think replicating the code was a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to this line

```
<%= link_to_function '[Delete]', link_to_destroy_task(task.id) %>
```

You're actually executing `link_to_destroy_task` function here, once for each task.

From the docs

**def link_to_function(name, *args, &block)**
*Returns a link of the given +name+ that will trigger a JavaScript +function+ using the onclick handler and return false after the fact.*

Never used this method, but it seems its purpose is to invoke JavaScript function, not Ruby function.
There're examples too.